# Capybara Scope within element to create array of href

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I'm writing tests that will look within an element which contains 4 href, and create an array of each href within it then click on each one in turn and expect a result.

Looking at the Capybara DSL docs, I can't see a way of scoping within, then calling all, kind of like this:

```
links = all(:href).within('id-of-element')
```

I would just leave  it as just `all(:href)` but there are 3 elements containing 4 href, I need to be specific of the element I'm interacting with.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybaras within takes a block and is called on the session, it's not a method you can call on nodes or "array"s of nodes

```
within("#id") do
  find(...) # result scoped to inside element with id
end
```

Your other option would be to just call find/first/all on a node which scopes it to that node

```
find("#id").all(...). # results of all are scoped to element with id
```

Comment: Just what I needed. You're fast becoming my Oracle Mr Walpole. Is there somewhere to find good documentation on Capybara other than Jnicklas git wike?

Comment: @tom The best documentation really is just the documentation - For general usage after setup start at http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element and go from there

Comment: Thanks @Tom Walpole